# How to change Authentication in sharepoint server 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2007, moss

how to change Authentication in sharepoint server 2010? By default it takes windows authentication.

After creating website it is possible to change authentication name in website if it possible how it so?

Comment: You can set authentication options while creating web application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change windows auth to form based auth you can follow these steps:
http://blog.summitcloud.com/2009/11/forms-based-authentication-sharepoint-2010-fb/